# How to query in Rails jsonb boolean attribute in postgres database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb, ruby-on-rails-7

In Rails 7, I do have following Council model with settings JSONb hash.
I want to get all Councils where `innov_funnel_connected: true` in `settings` `jsonb` column.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: councils
#
#  id                                         :uuid             not null, primary key                                
#  name                                       :string
#  settings                                   :jsonb            not null

class Council < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :settings, HashSerializer
end

class HashSerializer
  def self.dump(hash)
    hash.to_json
  end

  def self.load(jsonb)
    hash = JSON.load(jsonb) if jsonb.class == String
    HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(hash)
  end
end
```

```
irb > Council.last
=> #<Council:0x000000010bf81e00
 id: "13df8a20-002c-45c1-9845-1815591688b6",
 name: "Ford123",
 settings: {"innov_funnel_connected"=>true}>

irb > Council.last.settings
=> {"innov_funnel_connected"=>true}

irb> Council.where("(settings ->> 'innov_funnel_connected')::boolean is true")
  Council Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "councils".* FROM "councils" WHERE ((settings ->> 'innov_funnel_connected')::boolean is true)
=> []

irb> Council.where("settings::jsonb @> ?", { "innov_funnel_connected" => true }.to_json)
  Council Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "councils".* FROM "councils" WHERE (settings::jsonb @> '{"innov_funnel_connected":true}')
=> []
```

```
irb> Council.where("settings ->> 'innov_funnel_connected' = true").first
  Council Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "councils".* FROM "councils" WHERE (settings ->> 'innov_funnel_connected' = true) ORDER BY "councils"."created_at" ASC, "councils"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = boolean
LINE 1: ...ils" WHERE (settings ->> 'innov_funnel_connected' = true) OR...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params'
Caused by PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = boolean
LINE 1: ...ils" WHERE (settings ->> 'innov_funnel_connected' = true) OR...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params'
```

```
> Council.where("(settings ->> 'innov_funnel_connected')::boolean is true)").first
  Council Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "councils".* FROM "councils" WHERE ((settings ->> 'innov_funnel_connected')::boolean is true)) ORDER BY "councils"."created_at" ASC, "councils"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...gs ->> 'innov_funnel_connected')::boolean is true)) ORDER BY...
                                                             ^

from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params'
Caused by PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...gs ->> 'innov_funnel_connected')::boolean is true)) ORDER BY...
                                                             ^

from /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params'
```

How to debug and find where is the problem.

Comment: perhaps you should stop serializing `jsonb` column, it is serialized by default already.

Answer (score 1):

The error:

`ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = boolean`

is telling you the issue.

From here

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

`json ->> integer → text`

So:

```
select '{"key": true}'::json ->> 'key' = true;

ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = boolean
LINE 1: select '{"key": true}'::json ->> 'key' = true;
```

Solution:

```
select ('{"key": true}'::json ->> 'key')::boolean = true;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Or the other way around:

```
 select '{"key": true}'::json ->> 'key' = 'true';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Comment: hmm, just tried your solution:

`)> Council.where("(settings::json ->> 'innov_funnel_connected')::boolean = true")
  Council Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "councils".* FROM "councils" WHERE ((settings::json ->> 'innov_funnel_connected')::boolean = true)
=> []` but got no results.

wondering maybe the issue is in actually how I save the data.

Comment: Yes, its something related how I store the settings with serializer.

`Council: settings: "{\"innov_funnel_connected\":true}">`

Comment: That looks like the data is being saved as a string not JSON.